# PHP Symfony API and jQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, symfony

I have a problem between server and client side. I have a Rest API on server side with PHP Symfony.
**Server-side:**

```
/**
* @Route("/advertisement/all", name="advertisement_get_all")
* @Method("POST")
*/
public function getAllAdvertisement()
{
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    $content = $this->get("request")->getContent();
    $advertisemenetService = $this->container->get("advertisementservices");
    $response = $advertisemenetService->getAllAdvertisement($content);
  } else {
    $response = new \stdClass();
    $response->error = true;
    $response->message = "Error occurred: You aren't authorized!";
  }

  return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

If I try it in DHC Rest Client Chrome Extension for that
`development.domain.com/index.php/api/v2/advertisement/all` with Content type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I got a proper JSON object. If I try the same with `application/json` the symfony say the following error for me: 
`Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "" at line 0. (500 Internal Server Error)`
[JSON response example](http://pastebin.com/F4tKXT5j)

**Client-side:**

How I said on the API tester I got a proper JSON object. My clientside code:

```
function sendAjaxRequest(method, url, data, contentType) {
    var response;
    $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: contentType,
        success: function(msg) {
            response = msg;
        }
    });
    return jQuery.parseJSON(response);
}
response = sendAjaxRequest("POST", "{{ path('advertisement_get_all') }}", '', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
document.getElementById("loader-container").innerHTML = response;
```

In this case I always get `undefined` on the client-side. I try to use the JSON.stringify on the response, because it is a JSON object.

Comment: You have not want to add `header` function when you use `JsonResponse`. Comment line : `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I throw away the jQuery Ajax, because it was too dificult to slow this problem, and got back to the XMLHttpRequest and using a callback function which I called when the AJAX getting the response.

```
function sendAjaxRequest(method, url, data, contentType, callback)
{
    var response
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response = xhttp.responseText;
            callback(JSON.parse(response));
        }
    };
    xhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    xhttp.send(data);

    return response;
}
```

The main problem, which occured: The response handler function always run sooner than the Ajax response arrived.

Answer (score 1):

Move the update of the loader-container into the success handler.

```
function sendAjaxRequest(method, url, data, contentType) {
    var response;
    $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: contentType,
        success: function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("loader-container").innerHTML = JSON.parse(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Basically I did the same solution just used XMLHttpRequest. It is a good solution too, but it was a little buggy for me, and this is why I changed it to the older solution.